# "No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver"

Tags: java, sql-server, ubuntu, jdbc

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and using Oracle Java 9.

```
$ java --version
java 9.0.1
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.1+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.1+11, mixed mode)
```

I have installed SQL Server jdbc driver (`sqljdbc_6.2.2.0_enu.tar.gz` in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55539)

```
$ ls /home/t/program_files/RDBMS/JDBC/mssqlserverjdbc_6.0/enu/jre*
/home/t/program_files/RDBMS/JDBC/mssqlserverjdbc_6.0/enu/jre7:
sqljdbc41.jar

/home/t/program_files/RDBMS/JDBC/mssqlserverjdbc_6.0/enu/jre8:
sqljdbc42.jar
```

I wrote some simple   code to test using the driver :

```
// JDBC driver name and database URL                                                                                                                                       
String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
// static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/"; // connect to a DBMS                                                                                            
String DB_URL = "jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost/STUDENTS"; // connect to a specific database in a DBMS                                                               
//  Database credentials                                                                                                                                                   
String USER = "SA";
String PASS = "password";

//Register JDBC driver                                                                                                                                                     
try{
    Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
}catch(Exception e){ //Handle errors for Class.forName                                                                                                                     
    e.printStackTrace();
}

    //Open a connection                                                                                                                                                    
System.out.println("Connecting to database...");

try(Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); // connect to DBMS, not to a DB                                                                     
    Statement st = conn.createStatement()){

}catch(SQLException se){ //Handle errors for JDBC                                                                                                                          
    se.printStackTrace();
}
```

Compilation is fine:

```
$ javac BasicOperations.java
```

Running isn't.

```
$ java -cp .:/home/t/program_files/RDBMS/JDBC/mssqlserverjdbc_6.0/enu/jre8/sqljdbc42.jar BasicOperations

Connecting to database...
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost/STUDENTS
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:703)
        at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:229)
        at BasicOperations.main(BasicOperations.java:46)
```

How shall I solve the problem?

Is it because I am using Java 9 and SQL Server jdbc driver has drivers for jre7 and jre8?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like format of database connection URL is incorrect.
Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/building-the-connection-url

To be specific: `microsoft:` should be removed from URL. This is the format:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://[serverName[\instanceName][:portNumber]][;p‌​roperty=value[;prope‌​rty=value]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks. That solves my problem. But I now has a TCP connection problem https://stackoverflow.com/q/47663342/1224441 Appreciate if you can take a look.